# Inconsistent Communication link failure (10060) error

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

Good day,

#### Environment

- Python: Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
- pyodbc: '4.0.0-unsupported'
- OS: Windows
- DB: SQL Server 12.0.200.8
- driver:  "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"

#### Issue

I keep receiving inconsistent error while pushing data into MS SQL database.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.\r\n (10060) (SQLExecute); [08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Communication link failure (10060)')
[SQL: INSERT INTO randata.[RAN_regional] (mbnl_cell_id, nominal_id, code, activity_id, acquisition_partner, dici_partner, design_partner, build_partner, [MS1_PreRequisites_ACT], [MS2_Nomination_ACT], [SurveyInstructed_ACT], [MS3_DesignSurveyComplete_FC], [MS3_DesignSurveyComplete_ACT], [SSR_Uploaded], [GA_Instructed], [GA_Submitted_FC], [GA_Submitted_ACT], [GA_ApprovedAcq_ACT], [GA_ApprovedRadio_ACT], [GA_ApprovedBuild_ACT], [GA_Approved_T&T_ACT], [GA_Approved_ALL_ACT], [GA_Rejected_ACT], [GA_RejectionReason], [GDC_Required], [GDC_Instructed_ACT], [GDC_Approved_ACT], [DD_Instructed_ACT], [DD_Submitted_FC], [DD_Submitted_ACT], [DD_Rejected_ACT], [DD_ApprovedBuild_ACT], [DD_Approved_TnT_ACT], [DD_Approved_ALL_ACT], [DNO_AC_ExistingSupply], [REC_UpgradeRequired], [DNO_AC_ProposedSupply], [ServiceRequestFormIssued_SMS], [InstructionToObtainQuote_ACT], [DNO], [DNOConfirmPaymentReceived_ACT], [LeaseReadInstructed_ACT], [LeaseReadComplete_ACT], [ACQ_LeaseExpiryDate], [ACQ_AgreementType_5G], [ACQ_WithinRights], [ACQ_TechnologyRestriction_5G], [ACQ_Antenna_DishRights_5G], [ACQ_Cabinet_CabinRights_5G], [ACQ_AssAprtStlwSprtRights_5G], [ACQ_RequiredUpgradeRights_5G], [AcquisitionInstructed_ACT], [PlanningTypeSSR], [PlanningConstraints], [PlanningTypeSubmitted], [PlanningSubmitted_FC], [PlanningSubmitted_ACT], [PlanningApproved_FC], [PlanningApproved_ACT], [PlanningRefused], [PlanningAppealSubmitted], [AcqPathSSR], [AcqPath], [LLAgent], [HOTsComplete_FC], [HOTsComplete_ACT], [SolicitorsInstrA1submtd_ACT], [LegalsInstructed_ACT], [TypeofLegalsInstructed], [EngrossmentIssued], [EngrossmentReturned], [LegalCompletion_FC], [LegalCompletion_ACT], [AHOP_Submitted_ACT], [AHOP_Approved_ACT], [Ready_to_Access_FC], [Ready_to_Access_ACT], [MS5_SiteAccessed_FC], [MS5_SiteAccessed_ACT], [MS5_ATRISK_SiteAccessed_ACT], [CallOffReceivedfromSWC], [CallOffSubmitted], [MS7_BuildInstructed_FC], [MS7_BuildInstructed_ACT], [BuildStart_FC], [BuildStart_ACT], [CivilsComplete_FC], [CivilsComplete_ACT], [RiggingComplete_FC], [RiggingComplete_ACT], [PowerCabInstall_FC], [PowerCabInstall_ACT], [Jointing_FC], [Jointing_ACT], [Metering_FC], [Metering_ACT], [FuseUpgradeComplete_FC], [FuseUpgradeComplete_ACT], [MS8_BuildComplete_FC], [MS8_BuildComplete_ACT], [DataFillRequested_ACT], [DataFillIssued_ACT], [DIC_FC], [DIC_ACT]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: (('AAB002', '', '', 'AAB002_55', '', '', '', '', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '', '', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '', '', '', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', None, '', '', '', None, None, None, None, '', None, '', '', '', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None), ('AAB014', '', '', 'AAB014_55', '', '', '', '', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '', '', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '', '', '', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', None, '', '', '', None, None, None, None, '', None, '', '', '', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None), ('AAB026', '', '', 'AAB026_55', '', '', '', '', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '', '', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '', '', '', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', None, '', '', '', None, None, None, None, '', None, '', '', '', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None), ('AAB063', '', '', 'AAB063_55', '', '', '', '', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '', '', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '', '', '', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', None, '', '', '', None, None, None, None, '', None, '', '', '', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None), ('AAB068', '', '', 'AAB068_55', '', '', '', '', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '', '', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '', '', '', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', None, '', '', '', None, None, None, None, '', None, '', '', '', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None), ('ABC002', '', '', 'ABC002_14', '', '', '', '', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '', '', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '', '', '', None, None, None, None, datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 17, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 18, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 23, 0, 0), 'Expired Lease', '', 'Not Detailed', '10A', 'Not Specific', 'Unclear', 'Yes', None, '', 'None Known', '', None, None, None, None, '', None, 'Qualified Consent (NTBUWOD)', '', '', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, datetime.datetime(2030, 12, 31, 0, 0), None, datetime.datetime(2030, 12, 31, 0, 0), None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None), ('ABC015', '', '', 'ABC015_55', '', '', '', '', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '', '', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '', '', '', None, None, None, None, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 2, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 2, 0, 0), 'In date Lease', 'YES', 'Not Detailed', '10A', 'Not Specific', 'Unclear', 'No', None, '', '', '', None, None, None, None, '', None, '', '', '', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None), ('ABC018', '', '', 'ABC018_55', '', '', '', '', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '', '', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '', '', '', None, None, None, None, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 17, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 22, 0, 0), 'Expired Lease', '', 'Not Detailed', '2A/1D', 'Equipment Room', 'Unclear', 'No', None, '', '', '', None, None, None, None, '', None, '', '', '', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None)  ... displaying 10 of 3432 total bound parameter sets ...  ('', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '', '', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '', '', '', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', None, '', '', '', None, None, None, None, '', None, '', '', '', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None), ('', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 2, 0, 0), None, None, None, None, None, None, '', '', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '', '', '', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', None, '', '', '', None, None, None, None, '', None, '', '', '', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None))]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
```

Tables defer from very small ones to ~10-20k rows and ~150 columns.
I use same parameters but error appears and disappears without clear reason.

#### My code

**Engine:**

I tried to change these parameters:

- driver
- fast_executemany=False/True

```
driver = "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"
        server = 'server'
        username = os.getenv('MSSQL_USER')
        password = os.getenv('MSSQL_PASSWORD')
        database = 'db'

        odbc_str = f'DRIVER={driver};SERVER={server};PORT=1433;UID={username};DATABASE={database};PWD={password}'
        connect_str = f'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={urllib.parse.quote_plus(odbc_str)}'

        engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connect_str, fast_executemany=False)
```

**Inject into MS SQL:**

I tried to change these parameters:

- if_exists='replace'/'append',
- index=False/True
- schema='randata'/no schema

```
df.to_sql(sql_table_name, 
               general.get_engine(), 
              if_exists='replace', 
              index=False,
              dtype=db_schemas.MS1_MS8_SCHEMA_MAPPING,
              schema='data')
```

Could you please help to resolve this?
Thank you.
Daria

Comment: I think I found the solution. I'm using Anaconda and though I installed pyodbc 4.0.30 with conda package manager, under the hood it is 4.0.0-unsupported. (Very poor job from Anaconda to be honest)

I removed pyodbc from conda and installed 4.0.30 using pip and that seems to solve the issue.

Comment: Did the solution work? I have exact same problem. I use pyodbc 4.0.30, though it give me OperationalError - Communiaction link inconsistently